# Contar recorrências em uma lista

Tags: python, lista

Fiz o seguinte código para contar as recorrências em uma lista:

```
n = int(input())
n <= 100 and n >= 1
lista = []
for c in range(n):
     lista.append(int(input()))
for v in lista: 
    repete = lista.count(v)
    print(v,repete)
```

Porém a saída que recebo é essa (Entrada: 56,70,67,56,90)(EXEMPLO):

```
56 2
70 1
67 1
56 2
90 1
```

A saída esperada era essa(é necessario o mantimento da ordem da entrada para a quantia de N valores na lista):

```
56 2
70 1
67 1
90 1
```

Comment: Oi, não resolve... Isso porque o reverse só mantem a ordem numa lista com o 3 e 2. Porém, minha lista pode agregar N valores, assim, o reverse não soluciona... Mesmo assim, muito obrigado pela atenção! @lmonferrari

Comment: E se a lista for `[1,2,3,2,2,1,1,3,2,2,3,1]`, deve mostrar em qual ordem?

Comment: Nesse caso, seria 1 2 3, porém falo de casos em que a lista é [35,231,12,543,12,35,12,76] no output eu gostaria de manter a ordem de entrada e retirar os repetidos que vem apos a primeira aparição...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, não use `count`, porque cada chamada precisa percorrer toda a lista para contar quantas vezes o elemento ocorre. Ou seja, mesmo se a lista não tiver nenhum elemento repetido, como por exemplo, `[1, 2, 3]`, ainda sim ela será percorrida desnecessariamente 3 vezes (uma para obter a contagem do `1`, outra para o `2`, outra para o `3`).

> Quando você percorre uma lista várias vezes sem necessidade, está criando uma variação do chamado [*Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) (conhecido anedoticamente por ser um "algoritmo ruim").

Então para contar os elementos, use um [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), como sugerido em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478426/112052), pois ele percorre a lista apenas uma vez e já guarda a quantidade de vezes que todos os elementos ocorrem.

Já para manter a ordem dos elementos, não adianta transformar a lista em um `set`, pois um `set` não garante a ordem dos elementos: a própria [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) diz que ele é uma "*unordered collection*" ("coleção desordenada"), então se quer manter a ordem, tem que fazer de outro jeito.

O que você pode fazer é usar um `set` para guardar os elementos que já foram impressos, e só imprimir caso seja a primeira ocorrência. Algo assim:

```
from collections import Counter

lista =  [35, 231, 12, 543, 12, 35, 12, 76]
contagem = Counter(lista)
visitados = set()
for n in lista:
    if n not in visitados: # se o número ainda não foi impresso
        print(f'{n:<4} {contagem[n]}')
        visitados.add(n) # marco que o número já foi impresso
```

Desta forma, quando o número aparece pela primeira vez, ele ainda não está em `visitados`. Da próxima vez ele já estará e não será impresso novamente. Assim eu imprimo os elementos na ordem em que a primeira ocorrência deles aparece na lista.

É mais ou menos a mesma ideia que [uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478435/112052) fez, a diferença é que lá foi usada uma lista em vez de `set`. Mas eu prefiro usar `set` que é mais otimizado para buscas (tempo constante, versus o tempo linear de uma lista, [veja aqui](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)), e como a cada iteração será feita uma busca em `visitados`, isso pode fazer diferença conforme a lista original aumenta (e também se tiver muitos elementos repetidos) - veja mais abaixo um comparativo entre as duas soluções.

Por fim, também usei [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (disponível a partir do Python 3.6) para formatar melhor a saída, que no caso do exemplo acima, será:

```
35   2
231  1
12   3
543  1
76   1
```

Mas claro que, uma vez tendo o algoritmo, você pode formatar a saída da forma que achar melhor.

---

Fazendo um teste rápido com o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), para comparar as soluções (`count()` vs `Counter`):

```
from collections import Counter

def counter(lista):
    contagem = Counter(lista)
    visitados = set()
    for n in lista:
        if n not in visitados: # se o número ainda não foi impresso
            x = contagem[n] # usando o valor em vez de imprimir
            visitados.add(n)

def list_count(lista):
    filtro = []
    for i in lista:
        if i not in filtro:
            filtro.append(i)
            
    for v in filtro:
        lista.count(v) # só pegando a contagem em vez de imprimir

from random import choices
# lista com mil números (de 0 a 99 para ter vários repetidos)
lista = choices(range(100), k=1000)

from timeit import timeit

# testando mil vezes, com uma expressão válida e outra inválida
params = { 'number' : 1000, 'globals': globals() }
print(timeit('counter(lista)', **params))
print(timeit('list_count(lista)', **params))
```

Retirei o `print` porque I/O pode impactar nos testes e mascarar os resultados, então eu só peguei o valor da contagem e mais nada.

Lembrando que os tempos podem variar de uma máquina para outra, mas de qualquer forma, na minha o resultado foi (em segundos):

```
0.0981796
2.2945525
```

Ou seja, usando `count()` e um `list` para guardar os visitados foi cerca de 20 vezes mais lento do que usando o `Counter` e `set`.

É claro que para listas pequenas a diferença será imperceptível, afinal, [para poucos dados, tudo é rápido](https://blog.codinghorror.com/everything-is-fast-for-small-n/)...

Answer (score 3):

Vamos usar o que o Python tem de bom... :)

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> lista = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2]

>>> c = Counter(lista)

>>> print(c)
Counter({2: 3, 1: 2, 4: 2, 3: 1})

>>> lista_sem_repeticao = list(set(lista))

>>> print(lista_sem_repeticao)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Veja que o método `Counter` que existe no pacote `collections` (padrão do Python, não precisa instalar) retorna um dicionário com a `chave` igual ao encontrado na lista e o `valor` a quantidade.

O método `set` retorna o tipo `set` que, por definição, é uma "lista" sem repetições. Coloquei lista entre aspas, pois **não** é o tipo lista.

**UPDATE**: Caso manter a ordem da lista inicial seja importante, o `set` **não** é a solução. No lugar disso, faça um list comprehension com um pulo do gato

```
>>> lista = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2]
>>> aux = set()
>>> lista_sem_repeticao = [x for x in a if not (x in aux or aux.add(x))]
>>> lista_sem_repeticao
[1, 2, 3]
```

O `Counter` também funciona com `Strings`

```
>>> lista = ["banana", "goiaba", "laranja", "banana", "banana", "goiaba"]

>>> qtd_frutas = Counter(lista)

>>> qtd_frutas
Counter({'banana': 3, 'goiaba': 2, 'laranja': 1})
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Oi, tentei usar esse metodo do set, porém ele inverte o 3 com o 2, o que não pode acontecer. Tem como resolver isso? Desde já, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando seu código/raciocínio, você pode utilizar um "filtro"(nova lista):

```
n = int(input())
lista = []

for c in range(n):
     lista.append(int(input()))

filtro = []
for i in lista:
    if i not in filtro:
        filtro.append(i)
        
for v in filtro:
    print(v, lista.count(v))
```

Entrada:

```
3
3
3
2
2
```

Saída:

```
3 3
2 2
```

O filtro vai conter a primeira ocorrência dos números na ordem em que eles aparecem.

Comment: Oi, esse set está invertendo a ordem do 2 com o 3, tem como ele não fazer isso?

Comment: @GabrielSchrader Um `set` não garante a ordem dos elementos, a própria [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) diz que ele é uma "_unordered collection_" ("coleção desordenada"). A única garantia é que não tem elementos repetidos. Por isso a sugestão de usar `reversed` é uma gambiarra, que vai "funcionar" às vezes por coindicência. Por exemplo, se a lista for `[3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4]`, o resultado de `list(set(lista))` é `[2, 3, 4]`, se usar `reversed` será `[4, 3, 2]` (ou seja, nenhuma das alternativas preserva a ordem original).

Comment: Vale lembrar que essa ordem resultante é detalhe interno de implementação: como um `set` não garante a ordem, ele pode muito bem mudar sua implementação de uma versão pra outra e o resultado ser diferente (ele só precisa garantir que não haverá repetidos, tanto faz a ordem). Fazer qualquer algoritmo que dependa da ordem que o `set` retorna estará sujeito a erro.

Comment: Oi, obrigado pela informação! Sou novo no mundo da programação e as aulas EAD estão dificeis de aprender... Sabe me dizer se há outra maneira de remover os repetidos e manter a ordem sem o set? @hkotsubo Muito obrigado desde já!!

Comment: A pergunta original não continha o requerimento para tal ordenação. O reversed era gambiarra mesmo.

Comment: @GabrielSchrader, veja o update de minha resposta para manter a ordem

Comment: @PauloMarques ficou perfeito! Obrigado!